# Owncloud client : "No service keychain available" [Ubuntu 18.04]

Tags: 18.04, owncloud-client

The password of the of Owncloud client is not saved and the user is prompted to enter its owncloud password at each opening of the session.

The message "No keychain service available" is displayed.

It seems there is no correct integration of the owncloud client with the gome-keyring system (Seahorse) in Gnome 3...

Answer (score 6):

The gnomekeyring package is missing :

```
sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring0
```

Close the session, reopen it and enter for the last time the password. It should now be saved in Seahorse correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem but with `libgnome-keyring0` already installed. Other suggestions?

Comment: Try remove "--start --components=ssh" from gnome-keyring-daemon in startup entry? See: https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/1590#issuecomment-360965984